# reading from 2 files in a while loop BASH SCRIPTING

Tags: bash, csv

I have 2 files one named `Group.csv` Containing

```
thisisgroupone
```

and another named `Users.csv`

```
Testuser1,Testuser2,TestUser3
```

This my script so far:

```
# this part of the script will now add the created users into the created group!
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
        usermod  -g $READ GROUP.CSV$ $col1
        usermod  -g $READ GROUP.CSV$ $col2
        usermod  -g $READ GROUP.CSV$ $col3

    done < Users.csv

echo "Users now moved to new group sepcifyed in Group.csv"
```

- Im trying to figure out a way to read both files at once to complete this statement.

Thanks =D

Comment: Does the Group.csv contain only 1 entry?

Answer (score 4):

One technique is:

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
        read -u 3 GROUP
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col1
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col2
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col3
done < Users.csv 3< Group.csv
```

or

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3 && read -u 3 GROUP
do
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col1
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col2
        usermod  -g $GROUP $col3 
done < Users.csv 3< Group.csv
```

Neither of the above ensures that the files have the same number of lines, and you might want to check that.

Answer (score 2):

`paste -d' ' Group.csv Users.csv` will generate output such as:

```
Testgroup1 Testuser1 Testuser2 Testuser3
Testgroup2 Testuser4 Testuser5 Testuser6
...
```

so you can send the output of this to your script and it can read lines from a single file in which the first field of each line is the group and the remaining are users.

You can either use `|` to send the output of `paste` directly to your script. Or you can create a temporary file `paste -d' ' Group.csv Users.csv > temp.csv` and then use `< temp.csv` to read the file.